# How does the gridlock protect minorities?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, separation-of-powers

In [this video](https://youtu.be/Ggz_gd--UO0?t=392), at 6:32, Justice Scalia was talking about the separation of powers.

In fact, the Bill of Rights was an afterthought, and the "initial" Constitution did not include a Bill of Rights.

That's because the framers thought the main protection for minorities would be the separation of powers.

In fact Justisce Scalia says:

> Unless Americans can appreciate that, and learn ... learn to love the separation of powers, which means learning to love the gridlock, which the framers believed would be the main protection of minorities, the main protection: if a bill is about to pass that really comes down hard on some minority, they think it's terribly unfair, it doesn't take much to throw a monkey wrench into this .... into this complex system

What, in practical terms, would be the "monkey wrench" that is thrown in in order to stop a bill that really comes down on some minority?

Let's suppose that the majority of the people is Caucasian. For example, 80% of the people are Caucasian and 20% are Asians.

Let's further suppose, for example, that a bill is about to pass which says that the Asians pay all the taxes while the Caucasian pay no taxes.

Because 80% of the people are Caucasian, 80% of Congress is presumably elected by Caucasian people and reflect the will of Caucasian people.

The President is as well elected mostly by Caucasian people (at least assuming they are equally spread across the States).

How would the separation of powers, the gridlock, work out to stop this bill from passing?

Comment: I saw the downvote. Would ask for a real historical example of a bill that came down on minorities and was stopped by the gridlock improve the question?

Comment: This is not a question about established law.  It's about a system of government.  And "minority", in the context of the quote, clearly refers to the minority party rather than an ethnic/racial/demographic minority.

Comment: @grovkin well it's not a question like "democracy" vs "monarchy". I take the established constitution as given, and I propose an example and I'm looking to know how the example would work out under established law, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, Justice Scalia isn't talking about racial minorities. Instead, he is referencing the political theory of the Federalist Papers, which was concerned about "factions" some of which were minority factions, and some of which were majority factions, which the U.S. Constitution was devised to protect in different ways.

White Americans aren't now, and never have been in U.S. political history, a united front with a consensus agenda.

Legislative and policy making gridlock protects the status quo protections that minority factions (generally ideological and political rather than racial in this line of thinking) enjoy, against the "tyranny of the majority."

The main minority that had been protected, in practice, by these practices have been rural whites, especially in the South, trying to protect their prerogatives in the status quo, against a political coalition of non-whites and Northern liberals. The classic example, for example, is the filibuster, which has largely been used by this faction of conservative whites to defeat civil rights legislation, until the last decade or two, when the filibuster started to be used frequently for purposes other than defeating civil rights legislation as well.

Comment: Pardon me, but the idea that the poorest states in the country have some sort of privilege, protected by a parliamentary procedure, requires an explanation of its own. But leaving that aside, the Civil Rights Act was passed in 1964. Which was almost 60 years ago (rather than a decade or two ago).

Comment: @grovkin The decade or two time frame reflects the period when the filibuster started to be used on a regular basis for legislation other than civil rights legislation.

Comment: maybe I see it. Given there is a new election, and a new coalition is formed, the former majority becomes a minority, and the former minority becomes the new majority. Then protecting the status quo means protecting the minority (which was the majority in the previous term ... so it approved laws that favored itself)

Comment: @robertspierre Just so. Also, the ultimate status quo was the state of federal law as of the enactment of the U.S. Constitution in 1789, which was that there was no such law. The U.S. Constitutional process effectively requires and always has required something in excess of a bare majority of popular vote support to enact legislation and so, it has always protected large minorities (those without popular vote support but sufficiently large to prevent passage of legislation).

Comment: "Mr. Smith Goes to Washington" has nothing to do with the civil rights.  And its use of filibuster, as a plot device, effectively demonstrates Scalia's point, as it applies to filibuster in particular.  It was made in 1939.  Again, the use of filibuster, to oppose civil rights legislature, is known to be a one-time occurrence.  If you want to make the case that there was an era when it was systemic, that would be a historically-novel argument.

Comment: I suspect Scalia is talking about the FF concern about the rights of political minorities to prevent [this type](https://twitter.com/marceelias/status/1473118873302056961) of political persecution by majorities attempting to cling to power while anticipating upcoming election losses.

Comment: @grovkin The filibuster was in theory usable for all sorts of measures, but due to the norms of Senators, it was mostly used to stop civil rights legislation (which was not by any means a one time occurrence) and was used only rarely. "Political scientist Sarah Binder notes that of the 30 measures that were filibustered between 1917 and 1994, exactly half dealt with civil rights" even though civil rights legislation was a tiny percentage of overall legislation. https://www.facingsouth.org/2021/03/confronting-anti-civil-rights-filibuster This is a commonplace understanding of the history.

Comment: See also https://www.brennancenter.org/our-work/research-reports/case-against-filibuster “almost every filibustered measure before 1880 was eventually passed.” (due to limitations in the rule). It was only at the close of the 19th century that it started to be used to impact legislative outcomes, e.g., in 1891 after a series of filibusters by Democrats threatened to derail legislation authorizing federal troops to supervise federal elections — an early use of the tool to block civil rights protections for Black Americans. This changed starting in 2006.

Comment: I'll concede the point that it was not a one-time event.  Although I am still not convinced that "it was a tiny percentage of overall legislation" is fair comparison.  A more apt comparison would be to all legislation passed on party lines, or nearly on party lines.  If a large percentage of such legislation dealt with erasing the effects and after-effects of slavery, then it would make sense that would still be consistent with filibuster being a general tool to protect political minority rights rather than a tool to protect the privileges of a specific (pro-white-supremacist) minority.

Comment: To simply my last point, guilt by association is a political, rather than a legal, argument.

Comment: @grovkin Without citing to more political science literature than easily fits in the comments, I can't easily demonstrate it, but by any measure civil rights legislation was a tiny percentage of, e.g. party line vote legislation in the relevant time period). A lot of civil rights legislation was not party line BTW, due to Great Depression supermajorities followed by 1960s and later divides in the Democratic party.

Comment: @grovkin The question is about legal history and what the framers thought. Any discussion of the filibuster and legislative gridlock is really more political than legal.

Comment: you are the author of the answer.  you don't need to fit the citations in the comments.  we are discussing a point you made in the answer, so you can elaborate (if you find it interesting and appropriate to do so).